# Salesforce JOIN query issues

Tags: salesforce, inner-join

Salesforce below my JOIN query is not work,, so please help me

$query =

```
"SELECT s__c.Id,s__c.mobile_number__c,s__c.student_id__c,s__c.user_id__c,s__c.student_name__c FROM student__c AS s__c INNER JOIN uraan_db__c AS u__c ON u__c.Id=s__c.user_id__c ";
```

Error:=

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [sf:MALFORMED_QUERY] MALFORMED_QUERY: s__c.student_name__c FROM student__c AS s__c INNER JOIN uraan_db__c AS u__c ON ^ ERROR at Row:1:Column:118 unexpected token: 'INNER' in /opt/lampp/htdocs/ashvin/portal/soapclient/SforceBaseClient.php:799 Stack trace: #0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/ashvin/portal/soapclient/SforceBaseClient.php(799): SoapClient->__call('query', Array) #1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/ashvin/portal/soapclient/SforceBaseClient.php(799): SforceSoapClient->query(Array) #2 /opt/lampp/htdocs/ashvin/portal/student_list.php(24): SforceBaseClient->query('SELECT s__c.Id,...') #3 {main} thrown in /opt/lampp/htdocs/ashvin/portal/soapclient/SforceBaseClient.php on line 799
```

Comment: Please before you post look at the formatted version of your post below the edit box. Read the edit help re inline & block formats for code & quotations. Please in code questions give a [mcve]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: is this SOQL in salesforce or marketing cloud?

Comment: I'm assuming this is salesforce

Answer (score 0):

There are no joins in SOQL.

Please refer to this link to structure your soql queries

https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2013/05/basic-soql-relationship-queries.html